# CSS Textfield padding in different browsers?

Tags: css, browser, cross-browser, padding

Hi I am having some trouble with the padding in a text field in different browsers. Here is a screenshot of how they look in the two different browsers. That padding is set as:

```
padding:8px 0 0 0;
```

[image: Top one is Safari and Bottom is Chrome]

Does anybody know how I can make the padding the same in most browsers?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the two browsers? What's the rest of your CSS? Do you use a CSS reset stylesheet?

Comment: The two browsers are Safari (top image) and Chrome (bottom image), There is no reset on there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every browser render html differently so,  Remove **top padding** give `height` to your input field & same `line-height`. Like this:

```
input{
 height:40px;
 line-height:40px;
}
```

It's same in all browsers

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't using one already, you should be using a CSS Reset.  A CSS Reset will clear the default values that various browsers apply to certain elements, which allows for a lot more consistency.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you'll get it perfectly right, but try and explicitly set the `height`, `line-height` and `vertical-align` CSS properties.

Comment: No, that didnt seem to fix it :S